# Could you please tell me what this line do: sed 's/^.*-svn\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'

Tags: sed

Could you please tell me what this line do of sed
the expression is on the title

Thank you

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It replaces everything on the line with the number immediately following "-svn".
eg.:

```
blahblabhlabhlabhalbh-svn12345blahblhablhab
```

is replaced by:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

It's matching a string of [anything]-svn[numbers][anything], and replacing the line with the [numbers].

For example:

```
asda-svn123123bebeb
```

Gets replaced with

```
123123
```